# Sagemaker Data Capture does not write files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to enable data capture for a specific endpoint (so far, only via the console). The endpoint works fine and also logs & returns the desired results. However, no files are written to the specified S3 location.

#### Endpoint Configuration

The endpoint is based on a training job with a scikit learn classifier. It has only one variant which is a `ml.m4.xlarge` instance type. Data Capture is enabled with a sampling percentage of 100%. As data capture storage locations I tried `s3://<bucket-name>` as well as `s3://<bucket-name>/<some-other-path>`. With the "Capture content type" I tried leaving everything blank, setting `text/csv` in "CSV/Text" and `application/json` in "JSON".

#### Endpoint Invokation

The endpoint is invoked in a Lambda function with a client. Here's the call:

```
sagemaker_body_source = {
            "segments": segments,
            "language": language
        }
payload = json.dumps(sagemaker_body_source).encode()
response = self.client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                                       Body=payload,
                                       ContentType='application/json',
                                       Accept='application/json')
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
return result["predictions"]
```

Internally, the endpoint uses a Flask API with an `/invocation` path that returns the result.

#### Logs

The endpoint itself works fine and the Flask API is logging input and output:

```
INFO:api:body: {'segments': [<strings...>], 'language': 'de'}
```

```
INFO:api:output: {'predictions': [{'text': 'some text', 'label': 'some_label'}, ....]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue seemed to be related to the IAM role. The default role (`ModelEndpoint-Role`) does not have access to write S3 files. It worked via the SDK since it uses another role in the sagemaker studio. I did not receive any error message about this.

Answer (score 0):

Data capture can be enabled by using the SDK as shown below -

```
data_capture_config = DataCaptureConfig(
    enable_capture=True, sampling_percentage=100, destination_s3_uri=s3_capture_upload_path
)

predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
    data_capture_config=data_capture_config,
)
```

Make sure to reference your data capture config in your endpoint creation step. I've always seen this method to work. Can you try this and let me know? [Reference notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/introduction/SageMaker-ModelMonitoring.ipynb)

NOTE - I work for AWS SageMaker , but my opinions are my own.